# Wedding between orthodox and atheist possible?

Tags: eastern-orthodox, weddings

I was wondering in what conditions a believer could make a religious marriage with an atheist/agnostic in the Orthodox church. In some places I read that this is fully impossible, but some people told me that this could be accepted in some places.

NB: is it different in eastern and western Europe?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259). I would also recommend reading the [Help Center's](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) sections on asking and answering questions.